# UE4 - Changing ADS Camera when using a different weapon

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm very new to Unreal Engine 4 and have been following an fps guide online!
Currently have an AK and M4 in the game and can switch between the two using 1 / 2 on the keypad. I had to setup the first aim down sights camera to the AK and it works well! However if I equip the M4 and aim down sights then the camera is no longer in the correct spot and it doesn't line up at all with the ironsights. So I added another camera called M4A1 ADS Camera, but can't figure out how to switch to that camera when aiming down sights then going back to the AK camera if using that weapon.

Is there a better way of doing this or any tutorials / tips to help with the process for the future?

[image: Aim Down Sights Code]

[image: Select Primary / Select Secondary Weapon]

Answer (score 0):

If I want to try and answer your question I'd say that you should add a switch case or make branches to check wich weapon is equipped at the time.

But I'd say a better way to do this would be to add a camera to your weapon blueprint then you could access the camera from the weapon directly (assuming you have a master weapon class). This way you would configure 1 ADS camera per weapon and align it properly in it own blueprint.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Set View Targent With Blend" function to change your cameras, it is very good for changing speed, and blending other things.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but even cleaner than Deimos's suggestion would be to have an ADS camera component on your character and attach it to a socket you create on each of your weapons. You can adjust the socket position and rotation on each weapon's skeleton and then all you do from the character side is attach the camera to the weapon any time you equip one.